# Probability question about dice and triangle

Tags: probability

Throw 1 dice for 3 times, and get a b and c

Let $\sqrt a$ $\sqrt b$ $\sqrt c$ be the side lengths of triangle

1. Calculate the possibilities of the numbers could form a triangle.
2. Given that 1 angle is $60^\text{o}$, Find the maximum possible value of $\frac{bc}{a}$
3. Since that $\sqrt a$ $\sqrt b$ $\sqrt c$ are forming the sides of a triangle, find the probability that all the values of a, b, and c are mutually different from each other.

---

my solutions :

1) not possible to form = 1,1,4 / 1,1,5 / 1,1,6 / 1,2,6

then possibilities = $1-\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*3 - \frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*3 - \frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*3 - \frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}*6$ $= \frac {67}{72}$

2) if 1 angle = $60^\text{o}$. Another angle must be $90^\text{o}$ with $\sqrt 1$ and $\sqrt 3$ are the sides covered the angle $90^\text{o}$. And the opposite side of angle $90^\text{o}$ is $\sqrt 4$

so max value is $\frac {3*4} {1} = 12$

3) The numbers are work : 1,2,3 / 1,2,4 / 1,2,5 / 1,3,4 / 1,3,5 / 1,3,6 / 1,4,5 / 1,4,6 / 1,5,6 / 2,3,4 / 2,3,5 / 2,3,6 / 2,4,5 / 2,4,6 / 2,5,6 / 3,4,5 / 3,4,6 / 3,5,6 / 4,5,6

(only 1,2,6 is not possible). So the possibilities is $\frac {19}{120}$

are these correct?

Comment: For question $2$...which triangle?  The $(a,b,c)$ one or the $(\sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c)$ one?  In either case, why do you claim that if one angle is $60$ then another must be $90$?  Suppose $a=b=c$, for instance.

Comment: I don't understand your response for question $3$ at all.

Comment: for question 2, it means square root of a b and c. I considered it as 60 because I thought it would give biggest triangle. @lulu

Comment: @lulu for question 3, i wrote it from 1,2,3 / 1,2,4 .... 4,5,6 and i found that only 1,2,6 is not possible.

Comment: Well, there's no need to guess at which triangle is largest...there are very few cases, just check them all.  And for $3$, I still have no idea what you are saying.  Edit your post to add details.

Comment: I still don't have  idea how to find that. And for 3, I edited

Comment: I see the edit for $3$, but your calculation is inconsistent.  If your denominator is $216$ that means you are considering all triples, and order is significant.  So your count for the numerator is far off.  Of course, your denominator is wrong as well, as you need to exclude the triangles where the sides don't work.

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand question $1$ either.  It's all so vague...are you looking at the $(a,b,c)$ triangle or the $(\sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c)$ triangle?  And what's the source of this problem?  It appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264872/probability-question-number-from-throwing-dice-form-triangle#3264872) earlier.  Maybe the original source is clearer?

Comment: @lulu At the beginning of the question, it says "Let $\sqrt a$ $\sqrt b$ $\sqrt c$ be the side lengths of triangle" so I think it's the second one.

Comment: @lulu square root are sides. The question I posted before wasn't correct and I couldn't remembered them. It's from the test, I just asked my friends for exact details.

Comment: @ArsenBerk  Really?  I'd have guessed that "the possibilities of these numbers(a,b and c) could form a triangle" referred to the numbers $(a,b,c)$.  But my point is...why should we guess at all?  It shouldn't be difficult for the OP to settle the point.

Comment: @lulu You're right of course. It could be expressed in a better way without causing any confusion.

Comment: I'm not good with English, and couldn't remembered the exact words in the test. sorry, I have tried to explain my best

Answer (score 1):

For part $3$:

Reading the question as "conditioned on the fact that $(\sqrt a, \sqrt b, \sqrt c)$ form a non-degenerate triangle, what is the probability that $a,b,c$ are all distinct"

Note:  the "non-degenerate" is needed to exclude the triple $(a,b,c)=(1,1,4)$ and its permutations. It's possible that whoever set this problem did not mean to exclude this case, in which case the arithmetic below would require adjustment.

We start with all ordered triples of the form $(a,b,c)$.  There are $6^3=216$ of these.  Now, from these we exclude all permutations of $(1,1,6),(1,1,5), (1,1,4), (1,2,6)$.  There are $3+3+3+6=15$ of these.  Thus there are $216-15=201$ "good" ordered triples.  Of course, each of these is equi-probable.

Note: we can recover the answer to question $1$ this way, as $\frac {201}{216}=\frac {67}{72}$.

How many of these have the property that $a,b,c$ are all distinct?  Well there are $\binom {6}3=20$ ways to choose three distinct numbers from $\{1,\cdots, 6\}$.  From these we must delete the choice $\{1,2,6\}$ as it doesn't lead to an acceptable triangle.  Thus we have $19$ valid choices.  As each of these can be permuted in $6$ ways we get $6\times 19$ acceptable triples.  Thus the answer is $$\frac {6\times 19}{201}=\boxed {\frac {38}{67}}$$

Comment: TBH, I can't understand how you explained. This is for cases $\sqrt a$ $\sqrt b$ $\sqrt c$ are the sides of triangle which a b and c can't be same numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: order is important?

Comment: Well, as is usually the case with these problems, you can solve it in multiple ways.  I think the easiest way is to work with ordered triples because each ordered triple is equally probable.  If you prefer to work with unordered triples you certainly can, but these are not equally probable.  $\{1,1,1\}$ is much less probable than $\{1,2,3\}$.  Whatever you choose, you need to be consistent about it.

Comment: what if they ask for right triangle? a b c are mutually different. is it 12/201?

Comment: How do you get that?  Unless I am mistaken, the unordered triples that give us right triangles are $\{1,1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,3,4\} , \{1,4,5\}, \{1,5,6\},\{2,2,4\},\{2,3,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{3,3,6\}$ and to get ordered triples we need to count the permutations of each of these.

Comment: so it’s 6*3!/201, got wrong answer for test :(

Comment: I don't know where you got that either.  Trusting that I listed the unordered triples correctly, three of them contain doubles, hence have $3$ permutations each.  The other six have $3!=6$ permutations.  Thus the numerator should be $3\times 3+6\times 6 = 45$.

Comment: the test said a b and c are mutually different. so i got1,2,3 1,3,4 1,4,5 1,5,6 2,3,5 2,4,6 and each of them can be permuted 3!, so it should be 6*3!/201, or am i wrong?

Comment: Ok.  If you want non-isosceles right triangles, then I agree.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Seems correct to me.

**2) HINT:** If sides $a$ and $b$ form a $60^{\circ}$ angle, by Cosine Theorem, we have
$c = a+b-2\sqrt{ab}\cos(60^\circ) \implies c = a+b-\sqrt{ab}$ with $a,b,c \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Since it is asking for maximum value of $\frac{bc}{a}$, WLOG you can also find maximum value of $\frac{ab}{c}$ or $\frac{ac}{b}$. Also note that there are not too many cases where $\sqrt{ab}$ is an integer. So you can find it even by trial and error (Your answer $12$ seems correct but needs more justification).

**3) HINT:** In how many ways we can choose $3$ numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ where order of the numbers is important? Then $6$ of those don't form a triangle (because of $1,2,6$).

Comment: for 2) So I have to find from $c = a+b-\sqrt{ab}$ and find by trial and error? but 12 is correct right?

for 3) There are 20 ways to choose 3 numbers from 1,2,3,4,5,6 if 3 numbers are different and the order is important. So 14 is the answer for this question? but why is order important?

Comment: For 2), there are only $7$ cases to consider since what makes $\sqrt{ab}$ an integer are just the cases where $a = b$ and $a = 1$, $b = 4$. So you can easily go for trial and error. For 3), order is important because having $a = 1,b = 2, c = 3$ and $a = 3,b=1,c=2$ are to be considered as different cases for instance. So when order is important, you get $\binom{6}{3}3! = 120$. Then you exclude $1,2,6$ in which there are $6$ such permutations.

Comment: Oh I got it for 2, b=4,c=3 and a=1, For 3, still thinking about it

Comment: it's $\frac {38} {67}$ ? for 3

Comment: Yes, that's correct.